# Android Studio Gradle execution failed for task process debug resources

Tags: android, build, resources, android-studio

I've searched around and keep having this error. Other posts say "look above" for any clues to why the error is occurring. However, there's nothing apart from the following screenshot:

[image: Gradle Error]

Any ideas?

My build.gradle (the one *with* content) is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
}
```

Many thanks,
J

Comment: Yeah, cheers. See below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. I was being daft. I made a folder for a custom drawable set of icons ("drawable-flags") and the compiler was kicking up a fuss about that. I've put all the images in one folder now and it's working again.

I also installed an update to Studio which gave me a more thorough error message.

Comment: Is it sooooo hard for google to put a more meaningful warning? jeez

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong in resources. Wrong file name or folder. After